# I'm having problems nesting 3 navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm rendering a stack navigator on the home screen, but I need both a drawer navigator and tab navigator. I'm finding the Doc's aren't helping at all. I know i can nest them but cant get it to work properly.

I did manage to have the stack and drawer navigator on the home screen earlier. I attempted to make the header of the stack navigator persist, while navigation to the various screens in the drawer and I ended up destroying all the progress.

So I had to start again and I have no idea how to get back there. Does anyone know how I can nest them and access the drawer navigator with the onPress as I keep getting a warning in the console saying:   undefined is not an object(evaluating'navigation.openDrawer')

This is the code I have:

```
import React from "react";

import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";



const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

```
export const StackNavigator = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          title: "HomeScreen",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Icon.Button
              name="menu"
              size={25}
              backgroundColor="bold"
              onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
            ></Icon.Button>
          ),
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Body"
        component={BodyPartsScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Body Parts",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Diary"
        component={WorkoutDiaryScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Workout Diary",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="PreMade"
        component={PreMadeScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Pre Made Beast Workouts",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Stats"
        component={StatsScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Your Workout Stats",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="History"
        component={HistoryScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Your Workout History",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Chest"
        component={ChestListScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Champion Chest",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Back"
        component={BackListScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Beastie Back",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Shoulders"
        component={ShoulderListScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Shredded Shoulders",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Biceps"
        component={BicepListScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Ballistic Biceps",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Triceps"
        component={TricepListScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Trojan Triceps",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
            <Stack.Screen
        name="ExerciseSelected"
        component={ExerciseSelectedScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Customise Your Exercise",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
          headerTintColor: "#F5EDED",
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

```
export const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Back",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Membership"
        component={MembershipScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Membership",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Measurements"
        component={MeasurementsScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Measurements",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Feature"
        component={FeatureRequestScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Feature Request",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Contact"
        component={ContactSupportScreen}
        options={{
          title: "Contact",
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have nested the DrawerNavigator inside the TabNavigator And then the TabNavigator inside the StackNavigator. Everything can now be accessed from the home screen.